# what is the error in this program?

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, sqlplus

I have write the following pl/sql program and  unable to dectect the error :

```
 declare
 variable a number;
 b number:=2354;
 begin
 b:=:a;
 end;
```

the error in this  is

> SP2-0552: Bind variable "A" not declared.

plz help ...

Answer (score 7):

VARIABLE is a SQL*PLus keyword.  So you need to move it outside the PL/SQL declaration:

```
SQL> variable a number;
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2      b number:=2354;
  3  begin
  4      :a := b;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> print a

         A
----------
      2354

SQL>
```